# Refactor C function input-output and input-destroyed parameters in C++11

Tags: c, c++11, refactoring, legacy-code, perfect-forwarding

I have to work with a couple of legacy C-functions that as usual, have input, input-output, and output parameters and I want to wrap them in a C++ function.

(I used `double` as parameters for simplicity here, but I think the question is also valid for arguments involving a heavy `struct` with many members.)

The C function looks like this:

```
void Cfun(double* in_a, double* io_b, double* out_c, double* in_destr_d){}
```

In the documentation it says that the first parameter `a` is an input parameter, `b` is input-output, `c` is output and `d` is a an input parameter that on return will contain an unspecified (garbage) value. (and all the pointers must be non-null and only one element is taken, so there are no arrays involved.)

In C++ is obvious that one can refactor `Cfun` without loss in the following way:

```
double fun0(double a, double& b, double d){
    double c;
    Cfun(const_cast<double*>(&a), &b, &c, &d);
    return c;
}
```

Which should work, but also will involve copies where in the original C version were none. So, given our knowledge of `Cfun` (documentation + we know what we are doing) a better version could be:

```
double fun1(double const& a, double& b, double& d){
    double c;
    Cfun(const_cast<double*>(&a), &b, &c, &d);
    return c;
}
```

That is, `a` is promoted to a const reference, `b` and `d` are promoted to a reference and `c` is promoted to a return value.

This function can be used as this:

```
double a = 1.1;
double b = 1.2;
double d = 1.3;
```

i)

```
...
double c1 = fun1(1.1, b, d);
```

ii)

```
...
double c1 = fun1(a  , b, d);
// b has useful information here
// d has garbage
```

That is the second and third argument must be l-values, which is fine.

However there is a subtle difference between the parameters `b` and `d`. While `b` has useful information `d` is essentially destroyed and using its value after the function call would be an error in any case.

This situation reminded me of r-value reference and move in C++11. 
Where moved r-value parameters end up being in unspecified but assignable states.
This makes me think that an input-to-garbage parameter in C can be more or less mapped to r-value reference.

In other words, the wrapper can be written in this way to convey that the value of `d`, not only will change but it will be left in an unusable state.

```
double fun2(double const& a, double& b, double&& d){
    double c;
    Cfun(const_cast<double*>(&a), &b, &c, &d);
    return c;
}
```

**Does this sound reasonable, am I lossing something by defining this wrapper? Is something like this practiced in a similar context? Does this justify an r-value to a built-in type (like `double` here)?**

A slight problem I find is that the syntax will become more verbose, albeit more clear from the point of view of the usability of `d` after the function call.

As far as I can see now the possible syntaxes change to:

i)

```
...
//  double c = fun2(1.1, b, d); // now compile error, d is not a r-value
double c = fun2(1.1, b, std::move(d));  
// obvious error to use the value of d, since it was (probably) moved. However "moving a POD??"
d = 2.; // assignment is ok
```

ii)

```
...
double c = fun2(1.1, b, 1.3); // good, I can pass a literal now, nothing to misuse
```

iii)

```
...
double c = fun2(1.1, b, double{d}); // not clear, reaction "this seems a redudant cast"
```

iv)

```
...
double c = fun2(1.1, b, copy(d)); // verbose, but "d should be fine because it was copied"
```

where `template<class T> T copy(T&& t){return t;}`

**In summary, is `fun2` a better wrapper to `Cfun` than `fun1`?**

What if `double` is replaced by a struct with 29 member variables (and don't want to copy them) in all the examples above?

Comment: Don't over-engineer this. Simply pass `d` by value. `double fun (const double& a, double& b, double d)`. The local copy in the wrapper function will be destroyed, not the original value.

Comment: @Lundin What if `double` is replaced by a struct with 29 member variables (and don't want to copy them) in all the examples above?

Comment: Then you have to ask another question, as that's an entirely different case compared your posted example...

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction was that the C interface seems to take pointers to arbitrary (unknown from the interface ...) length arrays, whereas when you create the C++ interface you seem to assume (know??) that all arguments will really only be scalars? Of course - all good if that is indeed the case.

Iff the notion that all arguments are indeed scalars is correct I would just do:

```
double fun(double a, double& b, double d);
```

And be done with.

Comment: Yes, scalars, I rely in the documentation for that. The problem with this is that I am forcing always a copy in a place where there was none in C.

Comment: By the way, it is not uncommon to need this type of declarations with all pointers for scalars in functions defined in fortran code.

Comment: @alfC any indication as to what kind of project this is? Copy of integral types is decidedly trivial, so its not readily apparent as to how much we can help you. What are your use cases?

Comment: @jfh Yes, these are numerical libraries written in C or fortran which have weird sematic with respect to trashing some input parameters as scratch space. I find this a recurrent problem. This function is the easiest example: `rotmg`, the third argument is used as input an has no meaning after the function call http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/df/d28/group__single__blas__level1_ga97ce4e31b77723a3b60fb3f479f61316.html#ga97ce4e31b77723a3b60fb3f479f61316 .

Comment: @jfh,   another more complex example is `fftw_plan fftw_plan_dft_1d` which trashes the sample memory. http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-DFTs.html#Complex-DFTs  I want to express the fact that some data is trashed and I think that that can be conveyed with r-value function parameters.